# I am getting unknown ascii code characters in my program console output

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My program basically ask user for inputs and it saves data like login data, username in a text file and uses same file to retrieve data and displays in the output console. When program executes users can choose between options 1 to 6, option 6 is for existing out of the application and rest of the options from 1 to 5 are for users to input data and to view stored data in the file.

When program displays data in the console, I see lots of unnecessary `ASCii` code. Why is it showing up and how do I make them go ? Thanks!!

```
int main() {
    //Considering the max length of data entered (name) to be 15.
    char data[15];
    int n = 0, option = 0, count_n = 0;
    //This is the initial mark alloted to a subject.
    string empty = "00";
    string proctor = "";
    //Name of the file in which DB is stored.
    ifstream f("Example.txt");
    string line;

    //The following for loop counts the total number of lines in the file.
    for (int i = 0; std::getline(f, line); ++i) {
        count_n++;
    }

    while (option != 6) {
        //This prints out all the available options in the DB
        cout << "\nAvailable operations: \n1. Add New Students\n2."
            << "Student Login\n3. Faculty Login\n4. Proctor Login\n5. Admin View\n"
            << "6. Exit\nEnter option: ";
        cin >> option;

        if (option == 1) {
            cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
            cin >> n;

            count_n = count_n + n;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                ofstream outfile;
                outfile.open("Example.txt", ios::app);
                //The entire data of a single student is stored line-by-line.
                cout << "Enter your registration number: ";
                cin >> data;
                outfile << data << "\t";

                cout << "Enter your name: ";
                cin >> data;
                int len = strlen(data);

                while (len < 15) {
                    data[len] = ' ';
                    len = len + 1;
                }
                outfile << data << "\t";
                //Inserting empty data initially into the file
                outfile << empty << "\t";
                outfile << empty << "\t";
                cout << "\b \b";

                cout << "Enter your proctor ID: ";
                cin >> proctor;

                outfile << proctor << endl;

            }
        }

        else if (option == 2) {
            char regno[9];
            cout << "Enter your registration number: ";
            cin >> regno;
            ifstream infile;
            int check = 0;
            infile.open("Example.txt", ios::in);

            //This loop prints out the data according to the registration number specified.
            while (infile >> data) {
                if (strcmp(data, regno) == 0) {
                    cout << "\nRegistration Number: " << data << endl;
                    infile >> data;
                    cout << "Name: " << data << endl;

                    infile >> data;
                    cout << "CSE1001 mark: " << data << endl;

                    infile >> data;
                    cout << "CSE1002 mark: " << data << endl;

                    infile >> data;
                    cout << "Proctor ID: " << data << endl;

                    infile.close();
                    check = 1;
                }
            }

            if (check == 0) {
                cout << "No such registration number found!" << endl;
            }

        }

        //This loop is used to view and add marks to the database of a student.
        else if (option == 3) {
            char subcode[7];
            cout << "Enter your subject code: ";
            cin >> subcode;
            string code1 = "CSE1001", code2 = "CSE1002", mark = "";
            ifstream infile;
            int check = 0;

            cout << "\nAvailable operations: \n1. Add data about marks\n"
                << "2. View data\nEnter option: ";
            cin >> option;

            if (option == 1) {
                cout << "Warning! You would need to add mark"
                    << "details for all the students!" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < count_n; i++) {
                    fstream file("Example.txt");

                    //The seek in file has been done according to the length
                    //of the data being inserted. It needs to adjusted accordingly
                    //for diffferent lengths of data.

                    if (strcmp(subcode, code1.c_str()) == 0) {
                        file.seekp(26 + 37 * i, std::ios_base::beg);
                        cout << "Enter the mark of student#" << (i + 1) << " : ";
                        cin >> mark;
                        file.write(mark.c_str(), 2);
                    }

                    if (strcmp(subcode, code2.c_str()) == 0) {
                        file.seekp(29 + 37 * i, std::ios_base::beg);
                        cout << "Enter the mark of student#" << (i + 1) << " : ";
                        cin >> mark;
                        file.write(mark.c_str(), 2);

                    }
                }

            }

            //This loop is used to view marks of a student.
            //The extra infile commands have been used to get a specific mark 
            //only since the data has been seperated by a tabspace.

            else if (option == 2) {
                infile.open("Example.txt", ios::in);
                if (strcmp(subcode, code1.c_str()) == 0) {
                    cout << "Registration number - Marks\n" << endl;
                    while (infile >> data) {
                        cout << data;
                        infile >> data;
                        infile >> data;
                        cout << " - " << data << endl;
                        infile >> data;
                        infile >> data;
                        check = 1;
                    }
                }

                infile.close();
                infile.open("Example.txt", ios::in);

                if (strcmp(subcode, code2.c_str()) == 0) {
                    cout << "Registration number - Marks\n" << endl;
                    while (infile >> data) {
                        cout << data;
                        infile >> data;
                        infile >> data;
                        infile >> data;
                        cout << " - " << data << endl;
                        infile >> data;
                        check = 1;

                    }
                }
            }

            infile.close();

            if (check == 0) {
                cout << "No such subject code found!" << endl;
            }

        }

        //This loop displays all the details of students under the same proctor ID. 

        else if (option == 4) {
            char procid[7];
            cout << "Enter your proctor ID: ";
            cin >> procid;
            int check = 1;
            char temp1[100], temp2[100], temp3[100];
            char temp4[100], id[100];
            ifstream infile;
            infile.open("Example.txt", ios::in);

            while (infile >> temp1) {
                infile >> temp2;
                infile >> temp3;
                infile >> temp4;
                infile >> id;

                if (strcmp(id, procid) == 0) {
                    cout << "\nRegistration Number: " << temp1 << endl;
                    cout << "Name: " << temp2 << endl;
                    cout << "CSE1001 Mark: " << temp3 << endl;
                    cout << "CSE1002 Mark: " << temp4 << endl;
                    check = 1;
                }
            }

            if (check == 0) {
                cout << "No such proctor ID found!" << endl;
            }
        }

        //This loop acts as an admin view to see all the data in the file.

        else if (option == 5) {
            char password[25];
            cout << "Enter the admin password: ";
            cin >> password;

            //This variable value can be changed according to your requirement 
            //of the administrator password.

            string admin_pass = "admin";

            if (strcmp(password, admin_pass.c_str()) == 0) {
                cout << "Reg No.     \tName\tCSE1001\tCSE1002\tProctor ID" << endl;
                ifstream infile;
                infile.open("Example.txt", ios::in);
                char data[20];

                while (infile >> data) {
                    cout << data << "\t";
                    infile >> data;
                    cout << data << "\t";
                    infile >> data;
                    cout << data << "\t";
                    infile >> data;
                    cout << data << "\t";
                    infile >> data;
                    cout << data << endl;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `data` is initialized when you use it?

Comment: Try using  case statement, and separating each type of action into its own function. It will make it easier to to debug.

Comment: Note: You'll probably never write a program that uses ASCII. Go `chcp` and to see if @wally is right, you're using CP437. Also make sure you understand the /execution-charset compiler argument (and it goes without saying, /source-charset, too). There are various agreements between you, your compiler, your editor and your users' consoles. If you are all on the "page", it's all good.

Comment: WARNING: Amp up the warnings. Try adding ` /Wall /wd4710 /wd4514` to your compiler arguments. Warnings in C++ (and C) are a strong sign of very bad things. Some even go as far as `/WX` (treat warnings as errors).

Answer (score 6):

The ╠ character is a [box drawing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). In code page [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) it is represented by hex value `0xCC`.

In this case it is a [magic hex value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations) that means it is uninitialised stack memory.

The `data` array is 20 characters long, but it degrades into a pointer and the `operator<<` outputs characters until it gets a null character. So in this case lots of uninitialized memory ╠ characters until a `\0` character is found in memory.

---

It seems that the uninitialized `data` variable was written to the file on a previous run and now it is read back as-is. If the read was unsuccessful it would probably have placed a `\0` in the first position of the `data` `char` array and there would have been no output in that case.

I ran the program with an empty input file and added a single student. This was stored in the text file (viewed with Visual Studio's text editor):

```
REGNUM123   Pete           ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ    00  00  PROC432
```

In this case `Ì`, or latin capital letter i with grave character is the `0xCC` hex value in [Unicode and multiple other encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8C). When adding the student the number of characters written does not necessarily equal the number of characters in the `data` array (15 in that case). They are written until a `\0` is found.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you have multiple buffer overruns:

```
        char password[25];
        cout << "Enter the admin password: ";
        cin >> password;
```

If someone inputs more than 24 bytes (characters) as a password, you will have buffer overrun of password. You should do it this way:

```
        std::string password;
        cout << "Enter the admin password: ";
        cin >> password;
```

The same thing is valid for output, you're potentially buffer overrunning `char data[20];`. Furthermore, you can't use `infile >> data` like that for reading from file. You have to use `infile.getline()`:

```
int col_count = 4;

while (true) {
    infile.getline(data, 20);  // 20 is the size of the buffer.
    if(infile.good()) {
        cout << data;
        if(--col_count == 0) {
            col_count = 4;
            cout << '\n';
        }
        else cout << '\t';
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: _"Furthermore, you can't use `infile >> data` like that for reading from file"_ You certainly can.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, you can without having a syntax error, but what happens when the line is, for example, 40 bytes long?

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking, or how it applies to this situation. If you want formatted extraction of a "token" from a file or stream, you use `infile >> data`. That is literally what it is for. You don't always want to extract line-by-line.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `data` is a `char[20]` in this case. There's no way to extract anything meaningful with it. the operator `infile >> data` will stop at any white space, not only end of line. There's no way to prevent buffer overrun if there's more than 19 bytes extracted.

Comment: While that is true, it is not what you claim in your answer (refer to the text I quoted).